# Confusion about when pagecontainershow fires in single page mode

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and I've created two pages:

test1.html:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="test1">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test1 page</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
                Test1 page
                <a href="test2.html">foo</a>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
        <script>
            $(document).off("pagecontainershow").on("pagecontainershow", function () {
                var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

                var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
                switch (activePageId) {
                    case 'test2':
                        alert('test2 page from test1 page js');
                        break;
                    case 'test1':
                        alert('test1 page from test1 page js');
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

test2.html:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="test2">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test2 page</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
                Test2 page
                <a href="test1.html">foo</a>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
        <script>
            $(document).off("pagecontainershow").on("pagecontainershow", function () {
                var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

                var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
                switch (activePageId) {
                    case 'test2':
                        alert('test2 page from test2 page js');
                        break;
                    case 'test1':
                        alert('test1 page from test2 page js');
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I load test1.html, I get the alert reading `"test1 page from test1 page js"`, which tells me that loading the page fresh triggers the `pagecontainershow` event. So far, so good. Now I click the link to go to test2.html and I get the alert reading `"test2 page from test2 page js"`, showing that the link to the test2.html page triggered the `pagecontainershow` event.

Now I click the link to go back to test1.html, but I get the alert `"test1 page from test2 page js"` which sees to indicate that the `pagecontainershow` event did not trigger when going back to test1.html. Is this how the event works, i.e. it only fires the first time each page is loaded? If so, is there another event that fires each time the page is displayed, whether via link or back button?

Interestingly, if I move the script block from inside the `data-role=page` div to outside (but still inside the body block) and clear the cache, I get different behavior. In that case, it seems that only the test1.html `pagecontainershow` event triggers, the test2.html event never triggers; I only ever see `"test 1|2 page from test1 page js"`, never `"... from test2 page js"`.

Still quite new at this jQuery Mobile thing, can someone shed some light on how this stuff works? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate from test1 to test2, jQM actually finds the first `data-role="page"` div and loads it into the DOM of test1 via AJAX. At that time, your script runs the `.off("pagecontainershow")` which deactivates the existing code and then activates the code in test2.  When you navigate back to test1, jQM already has it in the DOM so it just hides the test2 div and shows the test1 div. **The script from test2 is still active**.

If you move the code in test2 out of the `data-role="page"` div, it never gets loaded into the test1 DOM, so the original script in test1 continues to work.

Read this:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

If you want truly independent pages you can override the AJAX loading of pages, but then you lose the nice transitions. If you like the AJAX navigation, just put all your code in the first page (or file referenced by first page) and then any page spedific code can go within the `data-role="page"` divs as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ezanker. A follow-up question: if I disable DOM caching, which I believe is a thing I can do in jQM, will jQM run the test1 `pagecontainershow` when I go back to the test1 page?

Comment: @rmclo, it is a thing: http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/#option-domCache  You have a good test bed setup, so give it a try and see what happens...